# Geometry Insight

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: Original Question]

Hello,

I have a question for which I don't understand how the solution came about. In the above triangle, AC = 8, and BE = 6. AD and DE are the equal. Also CN and NB are equal i.e. N is the mid point of BC. The question is what is DN?

The solution starts by stating, create a line NF, where N is in between E and C and parallel to BE.
[image: Addition of Parallel Line]

From here Triangle ECB is similar to FCN with a ratio of 2:1 so FN is 3. Then DF is equal to DE + EF. DE=1/2AE and EF=1/2EC So DE+EF = 1/2(AE+EC) = 1/2(AC) = 4. FN is 1/2 BE = 3. So DFN is 345 right triangle. So DN is 5.

I have a 2 part question. First, it didn't occur to me  to draw that parallel line but what in the question would suggest that this is a good idea? I tried putting the triangle in a co-ordinate system but didn't get anywhere. I don't understand the thinking to get to the point where that this seems like a good idea.

The second, is there a different solution that would seem more straightforward?

Thanks,

Comment: FN is a [midline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_theorem_(triangle)) in the triangle ECB. It is quite standard to draw a midline.

Comment: Elaborating further, we want to exploit the ratio of lengths being 1:1. (If the ratios were 2:3, then you'd draw a 2:3-midline.)  $\quad$ Also, 6 and 8 and a right angle should cause you to think about the 6-8-10 pythagorean triple, so you might wonder about how it is relevant to the problem. $\quad$ Consider one-off cases. EG In the limiting case when $E = C$, then we can get $DN = 5$. So how can we account for $CE $ when it is non-zero?

Comment: Thank you for that elaboration. I didn't realize we should exploit that 1:1 ratio. I had a hunch that 6,8,10 triangle would be there but didn't know how to use that information. Thank you for suggesting the idea about what happens when E=C. Then for sure DN =5 by similarity to the big 6-8-10 triangle. But I am still not sure about accounting for CE when it is non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a different straightforward solution, set up the coordinate geometry with $ E = (0,0) $ (why is this a good choice?) $A = (0, 2b), B= (6, 0), C = (0, 2b-8)$.

Show that $D  = (0, b), N= (3, b-4)$ and hence  $|DN| = 5$.

Comment: Thanks. That's awesome. For some reason, I put C at (0,0) when E is the much better choice since BE and AE are perpendicular.

Comment: @MathNewb Right. I'm exploiting the perpendicularity to allow me to easily set values based on the length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation of the proof, using the midline theorem extensively. Let M be a midpoint if AB. Then due to the midline theorem:

- MN is parallel to AC,
- MN is AC/$2=8/2=4$,
- DM is parallel to EB,
- DM is EB/$2=6/2=3$.

Since MN$\parallel$AC$\bot$EB$\parallel$DM, we have MN$\bot$DM. Now, from the right-angle triangle MND we get DN$=5$.